# Error when setting G1 GC on Elastic Bean Stalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jvm, jvm-arguments, g1gc

I'am trying to set G1 GC on elastic bean stalk using JVM options by UI using the following argument:
–XX:+UseG1GC.

But when i try to restart the instance, the following error is thrown:

Error: Could not find or load main class ?XX:+UseG1GC

Why this is happening ?

Some informations:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Environment:

```
Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [en dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html) character `–` instead of hyphen `-` character. The JVM options are defined with a hyphen, it should be (notice the short `-`):

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
```